# Error: An unknown exception has occurred

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, migration-tool

While validating my changes to the sandbox with Force.com Migration Tool, I suddenly got the below error.

> Component Failures:
>    1.  objects/PersonAccount.object -- Error: An unknown exception has occurred.

The problem is, I have no clue about why is this happening.

To debug, I revert all of my changes back to a previous successful deployment version and tried to deploy again, but still I get the same error.

Could someone please help me with this as I have no clue why is this happening suddenly?

Is there a way to debug this?

Comment: Are you deploying multiple object with field history tracking yes ?

Comment: @PrabhatKumar Yes I do, what's with history tracking here?

Comment: Objects have feature that you can track history of their fields....I would suggest you to deploy objects separately. Check if it works. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After comparing the sandbox instance with production code base we found this issue is due to spring16(beta) release, there is something to do with the history tracking. We had history tracking enabled for the Account object though we haven't had it enabled for PersonAccount (this is not required in version 35)

As a solution I added `<enableHistory>true</enableHistory>` line to personAccount metadata file and it works!